# Cumulative Distribution Function applied to exponential variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let P be a program composed by two sub-programs that have execution time of T1 and T2 distributed with exponential law of parameters u1 and u2.

I have to calculate the Cumulative Distribution Function of the execution time and the correspondent average value in two cases (doing the necessary independence hypothesis):

1 - the two sub-programs are executed in parallel and program P will be considered as terminated when one of the two subprograms will terminate

2 - the two sub-programs are executed in paralle but both of them have to be completed before P can be considered as terminated.

Calculate value of CDF after 0.005 seconds and 0.05 seconds and the average value in both of the cases above.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are two conventions about what the parameter of an exponential  means (the rate $\lambda$ or the mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$) we consider two independent random variables $T_1$ and $T_2$, where $T_i$ has density function $\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t}$, for $t\gt 0$.

**Problem 1:**  The process terminates as soon as one of the subprocesses terminates. Let $X$ be the running time until the process terminates. Then $X\gt x$ if and only if $T_1\gt x$ **and** $T_2\gt x$. Thus by independence
$$\Pr(X\gt x)=\Pr(T_1\gt x)\Pr(T_2\gt x)=e^{-\lambda_1  x}e^{-\lambda_2 x}.$$
It follows that the cdf of $X$ is
$$1-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}$$
(for $x\gt 0$) and therefore $X$ has exponential distribution. Differentiating, we find that $X$ has density function $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}$. The mean of $X$ is $\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.

The usual name for the random variable $X$ is $\min(T_1,T_2)$. A similar analysis can be made for the distribution of the min of any number of independent random variables.

**Problem 2:** The process now terminates when the second subprocess  to terminate does. Let $Y=\max(T_1,T_2)$. We want the distribution of $Y$. The probability that $Y\le y$ is the probability that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are $\le y$. It follows that for positive $y$, we have
$$\Pr(Y\le y)= \left(1-e^{-\lambda_1  y}\right)\left(1-e^{-\lambda_2 y}\right).$$
The above gives the cumulative distribution function of $Y$. For the density function, differentiate.

Using the density function, we could then find the mean of $Y$. But there is an easier way. For note that $X+Y=T_1+T_2$. The mean of $T_1+T_2$ is $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$. Above, we found the mean of $X$. So
$$E(Y)=\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}-\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.$$

Comment: Thank's a lot man! Your clean explanation will be very usefull to me :)

Comment: You are welcome.